# Sketch $r=\cos(5 \theta)$? $r$ as a function of $\theta$ in cartesian coordinates

Tags: graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

I think I have to plug in numbers into $\theta$ such as 0 and $\pi/6$. What kind of numbers should I plug in ?

Sketch $r=\cos(5 \theta)$? $r$ as a function of $\theta$ in cartesian coordinates

Comment: If you do it by hand then take at which points you know $cos 5\theta$ for example take $\theta$ as  $0,\pi/20, \pi/10, \pi/5,...$

Comment: @cindy: Have you learned Polar Plots (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar+plot+r+%3D+cos%285+t%29+)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

r=cos(n theta) is n leaf flower
but when n is even it is 2n leaf flower

Answer (score 0):

The period of $\cos \theta$ is $2\pi$, so if you were plotting $r=\cos \theta$ you would plug in $\theta$s in that range.  Because the period of $\cos 5\theta$ is $\frac {2\pi}{5}$, your points should cover that range-that is, be denser than without the factor $5$.